# Multi-server n-tier synchronized timing and performance metrics?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, time, windows-server

[I'm not sure whether to post this in stackoverflow or serverfault, but since this is a C# development project, I'll stick with stackoverflow...]

We've got a multi-tiered application that is exhibiting poor performance at unpredictable times of the day, and we're trying to track down the cause(s). It's particularly difficult to fix because we can't reproduce it on our development environment - it's a sporadic problem on our production servers only.

The architecture is as follows: Load balanced front end web servers (IIS) running an MVC application (C#). A home-grown service bus, implemented with MSMQ running in domain-integration mode. Five 'worker pool' servers, running our Windows Service, which responds to requests placed on the bus. Back end SQL Server 2012 database, mirrored and replicated.

All servers have high spec hardware, running Windows Server 2012, latest releases, latest windows update. Everything bang up to date.

When a user hits an action in the MVC app, the controller itself is very thin. Pretty much all it does is put a request message on the bus (sends an MSMQ message) and awaits the reply.

One of the servers in the worker pool picks up the message, works out what to do and then performs queries on the SQL Server back end and does other grunt work. The result is then placed back on the bus for the MVC app to pick back up using the Correlation ID.

It's a nice architecture to work with in respect to the simplicity of each individual component. As demand increases, we can simply add more servers to the worker pool and all is normally well. It also allows us to hot-swap code in the middle tier. Most of the time, the solution performs extremely well.

However, as stated we do have these moments where performance is a problem. It's proving difficult to track down at which point(s) in the architecture the bottleneck is.

What we have attempted to do is send a request down the bus and roundtrip it back to the MVC app with a whole suite of timings and metrics embedded in the message. At each stop on the route, a timestamp and other metrics are added to the message. Then when the MVC app receives the reply, we can screen dump the timestamps and metrics and try to determine which part of the process is causing the issue.

However, we soon realised that we cannot rely on the Windows time as an accurate measure, due to the fact that many of our processes are down to the 5-100ms level and a message can go through 5 servers (and back again). We cannot synchronize the time across the servers to that resolution. MS article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939322/en-us

To compound the problem, each time we send a request, we can't predict which particular worker pool server will handle the message.

What is the best way to get an accurate, coordinated and synchronized time that is accurate to the 5ms level? If we have to call out to an external (web)service at each step, this would add extra time to the process, and how can we guarantee that each call takes the same amount of time on each server? Even a small amount of latency in an external call on one server would skew the results and give us a false positive.

Hope I have explained our predicament and look forward to your help.

**Update**

I've just found this: http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html, which might be promising. Perhaps a scheduled job every x hours to keep the time synchronised could get me to the sub 5 ms resolution I need. Comments or experience?

**Update 2**

FWIW, We've found the cause of the performance issue. It occurs when the software tests if a queue has been created before it opens it. So it was essentially looking up the queue twice, which is fairly expensive. So the issue has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is using the Performance Monitor that's part of Windows itself. What you can do is create a [Data Collector Set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749337.aspx) on each of the servers and select the metrics you want to monitor. Something like Request Execution Time would be a good one to monitor for.

Here's a tutorial for Data Collector Sets: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=591kfPROYbs

Hopefully this will give you a start on troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: we use perf mon a lot but we need to coordinate the trace across the entire stack, across all servers and tiers. We need to instrument not only the processes running on each server, but also the transmission and receipt across network boundaries. Without that, I cannot determine if it's the code, the layers, the hardware or anything else.

Comment: Could be, but we've done extensive testing. The network rarely goes above 5%. That's why I need to examine the whole stack.